# How to delete rows based on two fields?

Tags: pandas

I have a df with lots of ids and dates, I need to delete from this df rows with id = 4 where date != '2021-01-01'
This expression, I assume won't work

```
df_2 = df_2[df_2['id'] != 4 & df_2['date'] != '2021-01-01']
```

How else can I write the condition?

E.g.

```
4 2020-01-01
5 2021-05-01
4 2021-01-01
4 2021-09-01
```

Should become

```
5 2021-05-01
4 2021-01-01
```

Comment: You should add brackets when there are multiple conditions: ```df_2 = df_2[ (df_2['id'] != 4) & (df_2['date'] != '2021-01-01')]```

Comment: But this statement will not return the row with id = 5, won't it?

Comment: It should return it, because you specify that both those conditions should be ```True```, using ```&```.  I think you need to change ```&``` to ```|``` IIUC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add parantheses and chain mask by `|` for bitwise `OR` and swap `==` with `!=`:

```
df_2 = df_2[(df_2['id'] != 4) | (df_2['date'] == '2021-01-01')]
print (df_2)
   id        date
1   5  2021-05-01
2   4  2021-01-01
```

Your solution should be change with invert mask by `~`:

```
df_2 = df_2[ ~((df_2['id'] == 4) & (df_2['date'] != '2021-01-01'))]
```